# Routing issue using ui-router in <a> tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, loopbackjs

I have this code and I can't figure out what is wrong. I'm using the data from MySql in loopback.

```
<ul id="main-menu" class="main-menu" ng-class="{'mobile-is-visible': layoutOptions.sidebar.isMenuOpenMobile}" >
    <li ng-class="sideClass('{{ menu.link }}')" ng-repeat="menu in myMenus">
        <a ui-sref="{{ menu.link }}">
            <i class="fa fa-{{ menu.icon }}" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
            <span class="title ng-binding">{{  menu.label }}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My angular code is:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',     function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
$stateProvider
.state('home',{
    url: '/home',
    authenticate: true,
    views: {
        'wrap@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        }
    }
})
.state('users', {
    url: '/users',
    parent: 'home',  
    views: {
        'inside@home' : {
            templateUrl: 'views/users.html',
            controller: 'usersCtrl'
        }
    }
})  
});

Menus.find({

}, function(res){
        $scope.myMenus = res;

});
```

It use to work fine. I don't why suddenly it gave me ann error

```
Error: Invalid state ref '' ...
```

The $scope.myMenus:

```
[
 {
  "label": "HOME",
  "icon": "dashboard",
  "link": "home"
 },{
  "label": "Users",
  "icon": "users",
  "link": "users"
 }
]
```

the error message

```
Error: Invalid state ref ''
at parseStateRef (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular-ui-router.js:3358:45)
at link (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular-ui-router.js:3440:17)
at ea (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:73:293)
at D (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:62:190)
at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:55:105)
at D (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:62:134)
at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:55:105)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:54:249
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:56:79
at k (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:60:377) <a ui-sref="{{ menu.link }}">
```

Comment: What is the content of `$scope.myMenus`?

Comment: it holds the menu properties, i've add it to my question

Comment: One of your `menu.link` is probably `void` or `''`, and cause this error.

Comment: Please show more error msg?

Comment: that's what i didn't understand. cause the `menu.link` isn't empty. what do you mean that it's `void`?

Comment: i've added the error msg @WorkWe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. i was creating the menus array with permissions later in the code, so he couldn't read it successfuly. I have added some flag called:

```
$scope.showMenu = false;
```

at the begining. And in the html view i have added to the ul:

```
 <ul id="main-menu" class="main-menu" ng-if="showMenu" >....
```

And after I created the menu I change it to:

```
$scope.showMenu = true;
```